# Использование JavaScript в проекте c#

Tags: c#, javascript

Добрый день.
Можно ли как-то подключить к приложению на C# javascript и взаимодействовать с программой из javascript?

Comment: А что за приложение? Если это десктоп-приложение, то напрашиваается вопрос - зачем вам вообще это нужно? C# как язык куда более гибок и удобен, нежели JS

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант использовать Webbrowser
[вот пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3694080)

Answer (score 1):

1. если у вас веб-приложение, самое лучшее - это использовать браузер клиента. Можно также использовать сторонние библиотеки (их достаточно много)
2. Для клиентской части (или же веб-приложения, которое хочет делать что-то со сторонними js библиотеками, например, которые анализируют что-то интересное, но нет аналогов на C#), существует ряд библиотек. Я бы не особо советовал использовать браузер, как в ответе выше, но все зависит от задачи.

У разных библиотек различный подход к работе с js скриптом, есть свои преимущества и недостатки.

Из них я бы выделил

1. [EDGE JS](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/2)
2. [V8 .NET](https://www.google.by/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fv8.net%2F&ei=2I3cVLapGsz5aPDagpgE&usg=AFQjCNFi216bipqZ8WE16rOSjHuUinUPlQ&sig2=Cgle5Oa94PRM_x9YyYZcCA&bvm=bv.85761416,d.d2s)
3. [Javascript .NET](http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/)
4. [Jurassic](https://jurassic.codeplex.com/)

Возможно есть еще несколько библиотек. Думаю, если кто знает, напишет в комментариях.