# Как программно запустить скрипт на сайте?

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms

На сайте имеется такой кусочек кода
`<a class="but lov" href="javascript: FishStart('9fa8d687067ea297538a5f46e923535f',0);"></a>`
Как этот скрипт можно запустить программно? Только один нюанс, вот это значение `9fa8d687067ea297538a5f46e923535f`постоянно меняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

да.В коде javascript. Только соответственно функция должна быть сперва, а потом Вы её уже вызываете
FishStart('9fa8d687067ea297538a5f46e923535f',0);
Если из C# , то https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694028/invoke-c-sharp-code-from-javascript-in-a-document-in-a-webbrowser/3694080#3694080
[Как в приложении на C# WPF иметь доступ к функциям javascript и наоборот?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503293/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c-wpf-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-javascript-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82)

Comment: не понял, что да ?)) вопрос помоему был, как прогрммно этот скрипт запустить )

Comment: вот это ответ-программно запустить скрипт. А Вы что хотите? когда запускать скрипт? при загрузке страницы? или по какому-то событию?

Comment: Так я понимаю, что программно, как это сделать вопрос? Допустим на языке c# с помощью контрола webbrowser по нажатию на соответствующую кнопочку или по наступлению какого-нибудь события - запустить данный скрипт.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/115021/

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/317376/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-javascript-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5-c

Comment: спасибо, только зачем мне ссылка на данный вопрос?)))

Comment: Ой.др ссылка. В ссылке выше есть ответ . http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503293/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c-wpf-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-javascript-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82

Comment: жалко, что без примера, а только ссылок накидали, которых я и сам найти смог, ну за старания спасибо конечно.

Comment: этот же вопрос я сам задавал http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503293/  и там есть примеры в ответе -https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc452443(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Странно, но если просто попытаться запустить скрипт по имени функции, он не запускается... И вообще, я могу запустить скрипт на сайте, если, к примеру, не знаю что содержится в теле функции? Просто инициировать запуск скрипта